# PySCIPOpt issue on Linux server

Tags: scip

I face an issue of running code from PySCIPOpt. I am trying to read a bnatt500.mps file using PySCIPOpt to optimize it as a test. However I face the following issue:

```
cteckyan@interns-instance:~/scipoptsuite-7.0.0/build$ python "/home/cteckyan/nikhita.txt"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/cteckyan/nikhita.txt", line 1, in <module>
    from pyscipopt import Model
  File "/home/cteckyan/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pyscipopt/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from pyscipopt.scip      import Model
ImportError: libscip.so.7.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have previously installed SCIP7.0.0 using makefile instead of Cmake. I have tried deleting and uninstalling SCIP7.0.0, unpacking the tarball again, and reinstalling using CMake. I then reinstalled PySCIPOpt and face this issue. The code I attempted to run is:

```
from pyscipopt import Model

model = Model()

model.readProblem('bnatt500')

model.optimize()
```

Could anybody suggest an idea on how to fix this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the path of scip/lib (the directory that contains `libscip.so`) to your `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You can this by running

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<path/to/scip/lib>`

This will tell the system where to look for runtime libraries. If this works, you should add this command to your `.bashrc` or similar to load it automatically.

Alternatively, you could install SCIP globally into `/lib` or `/usr/lib`.

Answer (score 0):

you can check where is the file via

```
locate libscip.so
```

then establish symbolic links between different versions of libscip.so files

It works for me.